Existence of countably decomposable, nonseparable von Neumann algebra
TL;DR Does there exist a nonseparable, type II${}_{1}$ von Neumann factor?
I am investigating the various classes of von Neumann algebras and, importantly, counterexamples to inclusions. Specifically, I have the following chain of inclusions:
$$\text{AFD} \subset \text{Separable} \subset \text{Countably Decomposable}$$
for classes (not the set theoretic type of classes :)) of von Neumann algebras, where AFD/Hyperfinite means Almost Finite Dimensional and separable refers to acting on a separable Hilbert spaces in the GNS construction for one state. For sources of these inclusions, Exercise 7 in Part III of Chapter 7 of [Dix81] has, as a consequence, that all AFD algebras are separably acting. As for separably acting algebras being countably decomposable, this follows from all separable factors possessing a faithful, normal state, and the existence of a faith, normal state being equivalent to the von Neumann algebra being countably decomposable, shown in Proposition 2.5.6 of [BR87].
I'm trying to find counterexamples to these inclusions of classes. For separably acting, not-hyperfinite algebras, I found [Chi70]. However, I'm struggling to find a countably decomposable, nonseparable algebra. I did find Countable decomposable von Neumann algebra, but it is a bit too "trivial" for my liking. Of course, if you present this to an undergrad or even an introductory grad student, they probably wouldn't call it trivial, but the point of me asking this is to test how many counterexamples exist and, importantly, if only simpler counterexamples exist.
I know one possible direction to search for, those being the Type II${}_{1}$ factors. This is because they are defined by being the infinite-dimensional, tracial von Neumann algebras, meaning they have a faithful, tracial state, which turns out also to be normal. They are thus automatically countably decomposable, but I have yet to find a nonseparable example. Has such an example been shown to exist? Of course, there is, up to ${}^{*}$-isomorphism, only one hyperfinite Type II${}_{1}$ factor, but I now want to remove the hyperfinite condition.
Apologies if this turns out to be a quick google search away and I just missed it.
[Chi70] Wai-mee Ching. “A continuum of non-isomorphic non-hyperfinite factors”. In: Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 23 (1970), pp. 921–937. issn: 0010-3640. doi: 10 . 1002 / cpa . 3160230605. url: https : //doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160230605.
[BR87] Ola Bratteli and Derek W. Robinson. Operator algebras and quantum statistical mechanics. 1. Second. Texts and Monographs in Physics. C$^{*}$- and W$^{*}$-algebras, symmetry groups, decomposition of states. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1987, pp. xiv+505. isbn: 0-387-17093-6. doi: 10.1007/978-3-662-02520-8. url: https: //doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-02520-8.
[Dix81] Jacques Dixmier. von Neumann algebras. Vol. 27. North-Holland Mathematical Library. With a preface by E. C. Lance, Translated from the second French edition by F. Jellett. North-Holland Publishing Co., Amsterdam-New York, 1981, pp. xxxviii+437. isbn: 0-444-86308-7.

I'm not an expert on von Neumann algebras, but I think that the ultrapower construction might do what you want.  The ultrapower of a tracial von Neumann algebra is again a tracial von Neumann algebra, but it will almost always have non-separable predual.  In particular, if $\mathcal{U}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ is the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor, then $\mathcal{R}^\mathcal{U}$ is a non-separable II$_1$ factor.

There is a huge amount of such things. As Chris mentioned, for any II$_1$ factor $M$, $M^\mathcal{U}$ for any non-principal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ (or more generally any countably incomplete ultrafilter on any infinite set) is non-separable. There are even easier examples, though. Say, $M^{\bar{\otimes} I}$ for II$_1$ factor and uncountable set $I$ is non-separable. (If you choose $M$ to be the separable hyperfinite II$_1$ factor, this is even AFD - if, in the definition of AFD, instead of a sequence of finite-dimensional subalgebras, you allow a net...

... There are different definitions of AFD regarding this, whether or not to allow non-separability.) Also, $L\Gamma$ for any discrete, icc, noncountable group $\Gamma$ is a nonseparable II$_1$ factor.

You can also consider non-tracial example. For type I factors, countable decomposability and separably acting are equivalent. For type II$\infty$, you have $M \bar{\otimes} B(\ell^2)$ is a countably decomposable but non-separable II$\infty$ factor if $M$ is a non-separable II$1$ factor (and, in fact, any countably decomposable but non-separable II$\infty$ factor is of this form). For type III, you have, for example, $(M_2(\mathbb{C}), \varphi)^{\otimes I}$ for non-tracial faithful state $\varphi$ on $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and uncountable set $I$.

You can also have, on the other extreme, abelian von Neumann algebras which are countably decomposable but not separable. All such examples are of the form $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes I}$ for uncountable $I$.

Thank you Chris and @David Gao. With all this in mind, the general impression I am getting is that the question of the existence of this type of counterexample was not difficult enough to warrant an article, or comment in any book, unlike this other counterexample paper: “A construction of approximately finite-dimensional non-ITPFI factors.” Am I correct?

@DiracComb16796 That is correct, yes.

@David Gao If that’s the case, if you put that fact as an answer, since that specifically answers the whole lack of a reference situation, I can mark that as the accepted answer. Thanks for providing those examples, and pointing out the “standard-ness” of these counterexamples.
